# Нужна помощь с html таблицей

Tags: html, вёрстка

Нужно сделать таблицу как на примере, сколько не пробую не получается, буду благодарен тем кто поможет сделать что-то похожее, спасибо! [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не совсем понятно, в чём именно у Вас возникает сложность. Секции с текстом на Вашей картинке, к примеру, можно сверстать, используя те же самые тэги ```div```, просто для верхнего (там, где должно быть фото) нужно указать ```display: inline-block```, чтобы можно было выставить ему желаемую ширину...

Comment: использовать таблицы, не то что бы именно тут, лишнее. с появлением grid'ов, таблицы где угодно использовать - лишнее. секции оберните в дивы\параграфы а после `p:nth-child(even){text-align: right} #photo{float: left}` ВСЁ :3

Answer (score 2):

Вот так это можно реализовать, если Вам нужно именно через таблицу.

```css
table {
  width: 220px;
  border-spacing: 10px;
  height: auto;
}

td:nth-child(1) {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  text-align: center;
}

td:nth-child(2) {
  width: 100px;
  height: 70px;
  border: none;
}

.left {
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px;
}

.right {
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 10px;
}

.left_n_p {
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: left;
}

.center {
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Фото</td>
      <td>ФИО студента</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <p class="left">Тут должен быть текст</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <p class="right">Тут должен быть текст</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <p class="left_n_p">Тут должен быть текст</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <p class="center">Тут должен быть текст</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```